# por que pasa esto mi código js

Tags: javascript

```js
    let xMayor = 100;
    let xMenor = 0;
    let x = xMenor + xMayor;

    const a = 0.59912051;
    const b = 0.64030348;
    const c = 263.33721367;
    const d = 387.92069617;

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
      console.log(xMenor, xMayor, x);
      let resultado = a * x + b * Math.sqrt(x ** 3) - c * Math.exp(-x / 50) - d;
      if (resultado !== 0) {
        if (resultado > 0) {
          xMayor = x;
          x = (xMenor + xMayor) / 2;
        } else if (resultado < 0) {
          xMenor = x;
        }
      }
      console.log(resultado, x);
    }
```

La situación es que aparir de la segunda iteracion x sigue a puntando los valores iniciales de xmenor y xmayor, ¿por que no toma los cambios de estas variables?, si dejo `x = xmenor + xmayor` al inicio del for sigue sucediendo lo mismo.

Comment: En los valores iniciales x vale 100, en la primera iteracion le asignas 50 dentro del condicional, pero como resultado es menor a 0 (en tu segunda iteracion) tu condicion if (resultado > 0) la filtra y pasa al else if, donde no le asignas ningun valor a x.

Comment: @LucianoMontañez te puedo hacer una escultura?, gracias :)